# Excel Not Formatting Axis Labels Properly

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a Pivot Chart (Excel 2016) that displays the instances of a range of dates.

It is displaying the X Axis label as "21-Mar", "22-Mar", etc.

I would like it to display as "Wednesday, March 21, 2016".

I have tried formatting the date in 'Axis Options' -> 'Format Code' as well as using 'Format Cells' in the 'Row Labels' column in the Pivot Chart sheet.

Neither of these changes the labels on the chart itself.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that you have the Axis Field Buttons showing. Right click the one for your date axis. Select Field Settings then Number Format. From here you can set the date format you are wanting.

It should result in something like the below image.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but yes I tried that already and it is still showing the other format.

Comment: I added a screenshot of where I made the change. Making a change in the Row Labels column or through Axis Options didn't work for me either.

Comment: Yes that is exactly where I changed the date format.  It still is not updating in the Pivot Chart itself.

Comment: Are all of the values in the Date column of the source data correctly formatted as dates. If there are any values in the column that are not dates, it won't change the formatting in the Pivot Chart.